# What's Java standard for single line if statement?

Tags: java

Which of the below format is JAVA standard for a single line IF-Statement?
Please provide me the JAVA reference as well to support the argument. Thanks.

**Syntax-01:**

```
if (counter == 10) response.redirect("www.google.com");
```

**Syntax-02:**

```
if (counter == 10) {
    response.redirect("www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: closing because it is opinion based, my opinion second one for better readability

Comment: @JigarJoshi I would agree it would be opinion based if the question asked for the clearest or most readable format. Instead, it asks what is standard. There is a definite right answer, and a couple of the fastest typists have posted it.

Comment: @Patricia you are correct (about standard), I retracted my close request, also -6 doesn't look valid as well

Comment: Dangit, too fast on the close button. My apologies, voted to reopen. Patricia is correct.

Comment: Just because there is free speech doesn't mean the children need to hear all that swearing.  If you are going to exercise your right to not have braces, then be ready to defend your errors.  Research technical debt, code smell, [Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html) and Robert Cecil Martin, Uncle Bob, author of Clean Coder.

Comment: In support of reopen, note that the two posted answers reference the same document as standard, and a commenter would have posted a similar answer, as would I. It would be very difficult to support some other document as the relevant standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the old [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), it is the second.

Exact piece of the document: 7. Statements. 7.4 if, if-else, if-else-if-else Statements (page 12):

> The `if-else` class of statements should have the following form
>
> ```
> if (condition) {
>     statements;
> }
>
> if (condition) {
>     statements;
> } else {
>     statements;
> }
>
> if (condition) {
>     statements;
> } else if (condition) {
>     statements;
> } else if (condition) {
>     statements;
> }
> ```
>
> **Note:** `if` statements always use braces `{}`. Avoid the following error-prone form:
>
> ```
> if (condition) //AVOID! THIS OMITS THE BRACES {}!
>     statement;
> ```

After that and since the Java Code Conventions are really old (since 1997), this falls into a personal matter/taste due to code readability. IMO the second is just fine.

Comment: wow, I was about to comment the same, you type faster than me... hehehe

Comment: Page 12 in the PDF, BTW

Comment: @morgano yep, I just get the code from that part. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 6):

As per the Java Code Conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf, Chapter 7.4):

> if statements always use braces {}. Avoid the following error-prone
>   form:
>
> ```
> if (condition) //AVOID! THIS OMITS THE BRACES {}!
>     statement;
> ```